при GET запросе на Flask сервер получаю 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server
Есть самописный сервер на Flask с тремя функциями: добавить пользователя, отредактировать пользователя, посмотреть всех пользователей в связке с PostgreSQL. По какой-то причине работает только метод с добавлением новых пользователей, я вижу как они создаются в pgadmin, запрос POST на добавление отправляю через POSTMAN, но я не могу увидеть пользователей или отредактировать их. При запросе GET Postman возвращает: "error": "404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."
Проверила, что HTTP-запрос отправляю правильно, он выдает 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, если аргумент в виде пользователя забываю. Подскажите в чем, может быть проблема, я не могу определить даже куда смотреть.
Код ниже или https://github.com/Bluefire137/DishDash
server.py
import threading
import configparser

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort

from exception.exception import UserNotFoundException
from interaction.interactions import DbInteraction


class Server:

    def __init__(self, host, port, db_host, db_port, user, password, db_name, rebuild_db=False):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.db_interaction = DbInteraction(
            host=db_host,
            port=db_port,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            db_name=db_name,
            rebuild_db=True
        )

        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.app.add_url_rule('/shutdown', view_func=self.shutdown)
        self.app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=self.get_home)
        self.app.add_url_rule('/home', view_func=self.get_home)
        self.app.add_url_rule('/add_user_info', view_func=self.add_user_info, methods=['POST'])
        self.app.add_url_rule('/get_user_info', view_func=self.get_user_info, methods=['GET'])
        self.app.add_url_rule('/edit_user_info', view_func=self.edit_user_info, methods=['PUT'])

        self.app.register_error_handler(404, self.page_not_found)

    def page_not_found(self, err_description):
        return jsonify(error=str(err_description)), 404

    def run_server(self):
        self.server = threading.Thread(target=self.app.run, kwargs={'host': self.host, 'port': self.port})
        self.server.start()
        return self.server

    def shutdown_server(self):
        request.get(f'http://{self.host}:{self.port}/shutdown')

    def shutdown(self):
        terminate_func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
        if terminate_func:
            terminate_func()

    def get_home(self):
        return 'Hello, api-server!'

    def add_user_info(self):
        request_body = dict(request.json)
        username = request_body['username']
        password = request_body['password']
        email = request_body['email']
        self.db_interaction.add_user_info(
            username=username,
            password=password,
            email=email
        )
        return f'Success added {username}', 201

    def get_user_info(self, username):
        try:
            user_info = self.db_interaction.get_user_info(username)
            return user_info, 200
        except UserNotFoundException:
            abort(404, description='User not found')

    def edit_user_info(self, username):
        request_body = dict(request.json)
        new_username = request_body['username']
        new_password = request_body['password']
        new_email = request_body['email']
        self.db_interaction.edit_user_info(
            username=username,
            new_username=new_username,
            new_password=new_password,
            new_email=new_email
        )
        return f'Success!', 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.txt')

    server_host = config['DEFAULT']['SERVER_HOST']
    server_port = config['DEFAULT']['SERVER_PORT']
    db_host = config['DEFAULT']['DB_HOST']
    db_port = config['DEFAULT']['DB_PORT']
    db_user = config['DEFAULT']['DB_USER']
    db_password = config['DEFAULT']['DB_PASSWORD']
    db_name = config['DEFAULT']['DB_NAME']

    '''parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--config', type = str, dest = 'config')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    config = config_parser(args.config)

    server_host = config['SERVER_HOST']
    server_port = config['SERVER_PORT']'''

    server = Server(
        host=server_host,
        port=server_port,
        db_host=db_host,
        db_port=db_port,
        user=db_user,
        password=db_password,
        db_name=db_name
    )
    server.run_server()

Interactions.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from exception.exception import UserNotFoundException
from models.models import Base, User


class DbInteraction:

    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password, db_name, rebuild_db=False):
        self.engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}')

        if rebuild_db:
            self.create_table_users()
            self.create_table_dishes()

    def create_table_users(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    def create_table_dishes(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    def add_user_info(self, username, email, password):
        user = User(
            username=username,
            password=password,
            email=email
        )
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        session = Session()
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
        return self.get_user_info(username)

    def get_user_info(self, username):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        session = Session()
        user = session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user:
            session.expire_all()
            return {'username': user.username, 'email': user.email, 'password': user.password}
        else:
            raise UserNotFoundException('User not found!')

    def edit_user_info(self, username, new_username=None, new_email=None, new_password=None):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        session = Session()
        user = session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user:
            if new_username is not None:
                user.username = new_username
            if new_email is not None:
                user.email = new_email
            if new_password is not None:
                user.password = new_password
            session.commit()
            return self.get_user_info(username if new_username is None else new_username)
        else:
            raise UserNotFoundException



if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DbInteraction(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=5432,
        user='postgres',
        password='ghbdtn137',
        db_name='some_db',
        rebuild_db=True)

models.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, VARCHAR, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

#Создание таблиц Users и Dishes

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    username = Column(VARCHAR(50), nullable=True)
    password = Column(VARCHAR(300), nullable=False)
    email = Column(VARCHAR(40))

    UniqueConstraint(username, name='username')
    UniqueConstraint(email, name='email')


class Dishes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dishes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(f'{User.__tablename__}.{User.id.name}'), nullable=False)
    dish = Column(VARCHAR(100), nullable=True)
    user = relationship('User', backref='dishes')

config.txt
[DEFAULT]
SERVER_HOST = 0.0.0.0
SERVER_PORT = 5005
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT = 5432
DB_USER = postgres
DB_PASSWORD = ghbdtn137
DB_NAME = some_db

exceptions.py
class UserNotFoundException(Exception):
    pass

